# Envisioning Spherical Coordinates

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

Is there a way to envision these two equations in spherical coordinates without plotting a bunch of points? I'm interested in what the surfaces look like.

$$\rho=\sin\theta\sin\phi$$

$$\rho^2(\sin^2\phi\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\phi)=9$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume $\theta$ is the azimuthal angle and $\phi$ the polar angle. By definition, then, $\sin\theta\sin\phi$ is just the spherical coordinate version of $y/\rho$. So the first equation is just $y=\rho^2=x^2+y^2+z^2,$ which is just a sphere (what is the center and radius?). For the second equation we instead obtain $y^2+z^2=9$. Do you recognize this figure?

Comment: Ok, I under stand that $\sin\theta\sin\phi$ is equal to $y/\rho$ since $\sin\theta = y/r$ and $\sin\phi = r/\rho$. Is $\rho^2$ by definition equal to $x^2+y^2+z^2$? Assuming $y^z$ was a typo. I do recognize the second equation it's a cylinder that runs along the x-axis with radius 3.

Comment: Very helpful answer! I know understand that I should convert the trigonometric functions to get a better image of the surfaces.

Comment: @ShaneBird: I'd missed that typo ($y^z$), thanks.